# Split $_POST into Chunks

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post, split

I currently have an enormous form that has over 1000 variables that must be passed upon submit. Currently, PHP limits it to 1000 variables going through and I'm required to edit the php.ini to work around it.

I know it's quite bad practice but is there any way to workaround it--perhaps by splitting the $_POST variables into chunks in the same associative array hierarchy so that I can loop among the chunks and utilize them?

Comment: So increase the limits?

Comment: I would advise that 1000 is far too many `POST` values, if you are chaining multiple form values then it might be preferable to use sessions instead to store data before you have all of it

Comment: The form I have must be displayed and filled out on one page and I'm intentionally avoiding to edit the php.ini file. I'm looking for other possible alternatives to work around this inconvenience.

Comment: split he form up ,no wants to fill that much in at once

Comment: You could use Javascript to combine all the inputs into a single JSON parameter.

Comment: You would have to use JS and AJAX to first send half the data and once the server responds then send the other half. You are not going to have fun handling that on the server-side though... Changing the php.ini file **is** the answer. You are basically telling us that you are hungry but refuse the suggestion to eat.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Lol! Thank you for the clarity. The last message made me chuckle.

Comment: @theflarenet Glad I could shed some light on the situation. Overall I think Barmar's answer is excellent but the risk which you run is exceeding the `post_max_size` from (you guessed it) the `php.ini` file. Another risk you run is simply the fact of introducing non-standard form submissions is now another potential point of failure.

Answer (score 3):

Use Javascript to combine all the inputs into a single JSON-encoded parameter.

Here's how you could do it using jQuery:

```
$("#formid").submit() {
    var params = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());
    $(this).find(":input:not(#params)").prop("disabled", true); // prevent submitting the real inputs
    $("<input>", {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'params'
        value: params
    }).appendTo(this);
});
```

In PHP, you would then do:

```
$_POST = json_decode($_POST['params']);
```

Note that buttons are not included in the parameters encoded by `serializeArray()`. So if the PHP does something like

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

it won't work. You'll need to add that to `params` explicitly, e.g.

```
params.submit = "submit";
```

Answer (score 0):

**php.ini** file
By increasing limit of `max_input_vars` 
OR 
You can change it by .htAccess

```
php_value max_input_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 6000
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this. Any way without touching the php.ini?

Comment: Then try `ini_set`

Comment: Sorry! I misread your post. I have tried ini_set and the array was still truncated. (I even used 10000). Looks like this isn't suitable with ini_set.

Comment: I'm sry it can't be set by php. It can only done by php.ini or .htaccess